# What is a reasonable amount of time to wait when making concurrent requests?

Tags: multithreading, networking

I'm working on a crawler and I've noticed that by setting the length of time for waiting 1 minute per request has made the application more reliable and I now get fewer connection resets. Can you recommend a reasonable amount of time to wait? I think 1 minute is quite the belts and braces approach and I would like to reduce this ideally.

Comment: I don't think there'll be a straightforward answer to this, it may be too broad. But have you considered placing all urls to visit in a queue? Unless you're targeting a single (or a few) sites, you'll build a natural delay in just because you're visiting other sites. And not wasting resources by waiting.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Good point and a great idea! Ta